# Mac Pro 5,1 PCI GPU power 6/8 pin confusion

Tags: power, mac-pro, gpu

I have a Sapphire HD 7950 from eBay I got to go in a Mac Pro 5,1. It has dual 8-pin sockets. Being second hand it has no instructions/data sheet.

The one I already own [different Mac Pro] has dual 6-pin sockets, which was the perfect fit for the motherboard's 6-pin PCI power. Plug & go.

Google gives far too many opinions over far too many models for me to know what the solution is. There seems to be cable adapters for dual 6-pin to single 8-pin, which really doesn't seem optimal; single 6-pin to dual 6 & 6+2, which sounds a bit optimistic.

Simplest start point… can I use my two existing 6-pin cables in the 8-pin sockets, or will something go boom?

I can't seem to find a single 6 to 8-pin cable, of which I could buy two.
In terms of power requirements/stress, this Mac is never going to be used for anything more than video playback. I just want to get the Mac to run Mojave, rather than be stuck on High Sierra [Metal2 requirement].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2 pins more in the in the 8 pin plug are 1x ground and Sense1. Sense1 is only to inform the card whether a 6 or 8 pin plug is plugged in.

I think the big difference in your usage is that 8-pin plugs are able to pull 150 W, where 6-pin plugs only provide 75 W at max.

As far as I see the Sapphire HD 7950 needs 80 W at idle.

So I see 3 Possibilities:

1. Buy a 6 to 8 Pin Cable and risk your power supply ([amazon link](https://www.amazon.de/Cable-Matters-6-PCIe-Adapter-Power/dp/B01DV1Z32Y)) (worst idea)
2. Use the card with only 150 W max (75W from PCI Power Supply + 75 W directly of the mainboard)
3. Get another Power Supply

Comment: Sorry if I sound a bit dozy here, but just to double-check.. so PCi plus **two** 6-pin cables (using both the default 6-pin outlets on the mobo) would give me 75+75+75, or 75+75?? Looking at some old figures from [Tom's Hardware](https://www.tomshardware.com/uk/reviews/radeon-hd-7950-review-benchmark,3207-9.html) it seems it may pull 150-180W at full gaming or bitmining but only 50 on video playback. I very much doubt it will ever be gamed on, so I'd think I ought to be safe enough??

Comment: The bounty is yours if you could clarify the points raised in my comment. I got this working - but only by using 6>8-pin adaptors & even then only in another Mac. It would hang the first one. I've moved my older 7950 6-pin card to that Mac & all seems stable on both for now.

Comment: The PCI Slot itself can give you 75W. Every 6-Pin Power Connector gives you 75 W extra.
So 2 Power Connector give you 75+75+75W.

The Graphics Card shouldn't have stability problems when given less power, than it can handle. The card will only not be able to develop its full performance.

Comment: OK - thanks for the clarification. It turned out no matter which Mac I put it in, it was simply a no-show with 6-pin connectors. Cheapo 6>8-pin converters got it working.  On my main Mac, it's now been up three days [this machine never sleeps] with no issues. The older 6-pin card has been the same in the other Mac. Seems like I'm good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in the end it came down to "what works"…

Using two 6-pin cables, Apple standard as supplied with the machine from new, it simply refused to register to the PCI bus at all. It would light & the fans would spin, the machine would start up but register nothing in the PCI at all. I could test this by remoting into it with Apple RDC.

I got a couple of 6 to 8-pin cable converters, 4 quid[bucks/euros] for three with next day delivery on Amazon Prime [they were cheaper than buying just two] & it immediately works as advertised, right from the boot screen.

*Slight update* - well, for some reason it would hang the first Mac after a few hours, so I moved the card to my other. Now works fine. Older 6-pin 7950 moved to the first Mac.
I wonder if there's a difference in the PSU spec. Crashy Mac is a 'real' 5,1 3.33GHz 6-core. Stable Mac is a 4,1 with firmware upgrade, 3.46GHz 12-core. Maybe the dual CPU required a heftier PSU?

Anyway. Done. Next, Mojave… then who knows, Big Sur, now this is a spare 'experimental' machine ;)

*Further update as I'm prompted by the number of visits the question has had…*
Two years later, this is still rock solid. Whatever upset the more powerful Mac does not upset the single CPU Mac at all, running Mojave. I use this every day as an HTPC video storage/playback machine with 16TB of drives in it, HDMI & TOSLink to a TV & AVR. No issues at all. I allow it to sleep when not in use, but reboot it only every month or three.